# Load JavaFX CSS with whitespaces within path

Tags: css, javafx, path

Got a problem, loading an external CSS file, when the path to that file contains one or more whitespaces.

Following warning is displayed on the console:

> Sep 24, 2015 10:27:25 AM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged
>   WARNING: Resource file:////home/user1/css/**styles one**/theme.css" not found.

`getScene().getStylesheets().add("file:////home/user1/css/styles one/theme.css");`

Is this a known bug in JavaFX or is something wrong with my code?

Comment: If you downvote my question. Then say at least why you've done this! I already searched... but could not find any solutions.

Comment: Have you tried using `styles%20one` ?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha  : I just wanted to write that i found the solution :D its exactly as you mentioned. The path needed to encoded as URL.  Thanks. Write an answer so I can accept yours :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an encoded URL here i.e. all white space characters should be replaced by `%20`.

You need to replace `style one` to `styles%20one`

**Code :**

```
getScene().getStylesheets().add("file:////home/user1/css/styles%20one/theme.css");
```

You may not want to encode it manually, so you can use :

```
try {
    URL url = new File(fileName).toURI().toURL();
    String encodedFileName = url.toString();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I think the better solution, instead of manually encoding the path is this: `try {
  URL url = new File(fileName).toURI().toURL();
   String fileNameEnc = url.toString();
  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }`

Comment: The correct way is to use url.toExternalForm() but it does not make a difference because toString() is implemented as just calling toExternalForm().